# Pywinauto - Can't connect to office documents using the UIA backend

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm having an unusual problem lately that when I open some excel/word document and try to connect to it's process using -

```
app = pywinauto.Application(backend="uia").connect(process=19812)
```

It seems not to work, meaning that *app.is_process_running()* returns False and the *top_window()* method raises the *RuntimeError(No windows for that process could be found)* exception.

But if I run the actual executable program (Winword.exe or Excel.exe and not some *.xls file), it seems to work properly and everything seems to work fine.

I checked the UIA compatibility with inspect.exe on the documents and everything seems to be fine.

What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the python script with admin privileges solved the problem :\